# Azure Pipeline - npm install error 403 with Azure Feed

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, installation, azure-artifacts

My NPM install step is configured to use registries in .npmrc,

[image: config]
My .npmrc is as follows

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/_packaging/design-system/npm/registry/

always-auth=true
```

The Azure Artifacts feed is set-up, and a local `npm install` from my dev machine works completely fine. 
[image: azure artifacts]

However the pipeline's `npm install` job always fails with error 403.

[image: npm install in pipeline]

What am I doing wrong here? I've also tried changing the npm install task to use **Registry I select here**, and linking it to my "design-system" feed directly, but it results in the same error. I've followed all the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows, but it just doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problem solved. What I had to do was go under into the feed -> settings -> permissions, and add the `...Build Service...` as a Contributor.

[image: solved]

Microsoft should really add this as part of their documentation. Took me several hours of random attempts before I found it..

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution [as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. In my case I experienced the same error despite the fact that I have had the build service already as Contributor. It helped me to remove it and then add it again as Contributor.

Comment: Do you know why the contributor role is needed?

Answer (score 2):

This is a different solution for the same message, although, in this case, it will fail from any location.

Trying to publish a package version previous to the last one published on the feed will also return the 403 Forbidden error, even if it's not a permissions issue.

Updating the package version to one increment after the current version will solve the problem.